# USB detection problem!

Tags: 20.04

I have the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit OS.
My problem is that the system does not recognize or detect my USB, I looked in the disk manager but there was no entry or access to it, but what it does detect in the USB port is the mouse. Could you tell me what the problem will be?

Comment: run `lsblk` and check if it's showing USB whose device name maybe `sdb`. Then mount it `mount  /dev/sdb /media/`