# Kobo Aura One reader USB device not recognised in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 (linux 5.4.0-31-generic) on three separate machines (One Ubuntu Mate, two Lubuntu) and my two Kobo ereaders are not recognised as devices. They are not even seen as drives when I do "lsusb". The reader itself "connects" to my PC, and is charging OK but Ubuntu does not seem to see it.

Since there is nothing for me to latch onto I am at a loss as to what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: I've got same issue, my 20.04 machine won't detect Kobo as well (works on other 19.04 computer). Doesn't detect other USB devices either, seems similar to these issues 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234993/ubuntu-20-04-doesn-t-recognise-hard-drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242362/usb-detection-problem

Comment: upd: I tried installing tlp following this advice https://askubuntu.com/a/1236869/427470, and without doing anything else (didn't even tweak anything) USB devices including Kobo started working. I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence, or installing tlp adjusts some settings that fix it, but maybe it would help you too.

Comment: Could you run these on separate terminal and report output when you plug in Kobo: `sudo udevadm monitor -u` and `journalctl --follow` . Had you tried different USB cables? BTW, short ones are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a kindle and Ubuntu 20.04. The kindle did show up as a device in the Disks app, but it was not mounted somehow. In the end I reset the kindle to factory settings and everything worked.

If you do not want to reset your device, maybe this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315063/221757) will give you some answers.